# Why the cardinality of $\{f:\emptyset\to \emptyset \mid f\text{ a function}\}$ is one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why the cardinality of $$\{f:\emptyset\to \emptyset \mid f\text{ a function}\}$$ is one ? There is no such function... the cardinality should be $0$, no ? How could a function $$f:\emptyset \to \emptyset$$ looks like ?

Comment: Where is it said that the cardinality is 1?

Comment: It's because the only such function is the empty function.